# iTerm open chrome-devtools link

Tags: google-chrome, iterm

With node's new chrome inspector functionality, I find myself copy/pasting this link into chrome over and over because iTerm doesn't seem to know how to handle it:

```
To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@60cd6e859b9f557d2312f5bf532f6aec5f284980/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:9229/node
```

Debugger attached.

[image]

Any thoughts on how to get iterm to open up chrome when cmd-clicking this link?

Comment: Cmd-click, no. *But* you can highlight the `uri`, right click and `Open Selection as Url`. You might need to assign `chrome-devtools:` as a url scheme handled by Google Chrome if you have not already done so

Comment: I was able to make this work in iTerm by following the instructions here: https://medium.com/@cnadeau_/launch-chrome-devtools-url-from-iterm-in-a-single-click-9c93ce86498c#.4uxa1ws8r  I didn't need to download the nightly build, so I assume the latest version (I'm on 3.0.14) already has the fix.

Comment: did you find a cmd+click solution yet?

Comment: I am using this extension for chrome which keeps the inspector panel open for you. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nodejs-v8-inspector-manag/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj